# wcf userName authentication with message security over https

Tags: c#, wcf, security

Here is the situation, I want many clients to call my web service using username authentication over https. Security is the first priority so I am thinking of using wshttpbinding with message security. I don't know though if my thoughts are correct.
The thing is that I have already something that works but I don't know if it needs changes to achieve better security.
Here is what it's done by now.

```xml
<services>
  <service name="myService" behaviorConfiguration="myBehavior" >
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="myIService" bindingConfiguration="RequestUserName_BasicHttp" >
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/myService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="RequestUserName_BasicHttp">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

 <serviceCredentials>
   <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="myvalidator, myNamespace"/>
 </serviceCredentials>
```

So, by this way (which works) I don't think that I have best security (at least I need to send requests over https). What can I do to achieve better/best security? I have tried with wshttpbinding and https but I have some problems with certificates.
The development enviroment is Windows XP, VS2010, IIS7.5 express.
And there are a class library describing the Service and a consoleClient app for consuming it...The client has it's own app.config file in which there are the credentials (username and password).

Comment: Can you please explain what type of security you want to implement? only user id and password verification and allow or restrict the user to access specified resources or encryption and decryption of messages transmitted between client and service?

Comment: I need both, I need username authentication and encryprtion of message so don't be just plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are already implementing user id and password verification and if you want to perform encryption and decryption of messages you must use Certificates with HttpsBinding or WsHttpBinding. More information about authentication and authorization in wcf please go through this [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff405740.aspx)

Comment: so If I understand, you suggest to use Certificate in clientCredentialType instead of Basic...
something like that??
<bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding> 
        <binding name="something">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential"> 
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

could you provide me an example because download link in msdn you said is not working...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I took into consideration Ramesh Babu answer and I change a little bit my project.
So instead of creating a class library for wcf service I created a WCF Service Application (there is this option in VS2010).Everything else remained unchanged so I made a new Web.config file like this

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="MyBinding">
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="MyBehavior" name="myName">
                <endpoint address="myService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                          bindingConfiguration="MyBinding"
                          contract="myService.ImyService" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"
contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:44400/" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="MyBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebugincludeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                    <serviceCredentials>
                        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="myService.Authentication.CustomValidator, myService" />

                        <serviceCertificate
                            findValue="MyCertificate"
                            x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"
                            storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                            storeName="My" />

                    </serviceCredentials>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>

    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    </system.webServer>

    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="myEntities" connectionString="......" />
    </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

so I needed to create a certificate and I used SelfCert to create one and copy it to TrustedPeople (typing mmc in run).
After this I created a console app to consume thw service and app.config file of app was built automatically.